# File transfer tools for linux with support of zero-copy transfer

Tags: linux, networking, backup, rsync, file-transfer

Are there small and simple file transfer tools for Linux, which can use "zero-copy" style of transferring files from HDD (SSD) to tcp socket, and back?

I want to often send huge amount of uncompressible unique data (tens-hundreds of GB) with Ethernet, 1 Gbit or may be 10 Gbit, between two PCs. I need no encryption, nor compression, no deduplication/delta transfers and no any extra checksumming from the tool (so, no `scp` and no default `rsync`); just high bandwidth of linear disk reads and high network utilization.

And also I want the tool not to make lot of memory copies, but use "zero-copy" infrastructure of modern Linux kernel: syscalls `splice`, `vmsplice`, `sendfile`, etc. With zero-copy tool can skip most data copying procedures, instructing kernel to read some data from HDD/SSD/RAID (DMA read to pagecache) and then repack it into packets and to program network card to doing DMA directly from pagecache. This "zerocopy" approach will lower system load from the transfer, because CPU will not have to crumble up every byte of file data. One side of transfer may have slow CPU...

Comment: Apache has [**sendfile**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#enablesendfile) support.

Comment: This question might be better suited for [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Cristian Ciupitu, Apache is huge daemon. I searching for something small and simple, like rsync+rsyncd/scp+ssd/netcat...

Comment: Interesting thread from fa.linux.kernel: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fa.linux.kernel/0Gw6MIvix_k "splice/vmsplice performance test results" by Jim Schutt, 2006-11-16 with source code of "dnd" single-file disk-network-disk transfer tool. It have several methods of data reading/writing/splicing.

Comment: Have you seen this article? http://blog.superpat.com/2010/06/01/zero-copy-in-linux-with-sendfile-and-splice/comment-page-1/